# Efficient tree list

Tags: c#, tree, filesystems, explorer

I'm trying to create a Windows Explorer using a recursive node function within a tree list.  I'm wondering if there is a way to only load information that has been clicked — for instance I can load all the drives using

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
```

giving me something resembling

- C://
- D://
- E://

and if I were to load everything from every drive it would get pretty large pretty quickly.  So I'm wondering if there is a good way to just initialize with the drives and once it is enlarged it would only populate the drive that was clicked.

- C://

  - Folder1
  - Folder2
  - Folder3

    - file1
    - etc.
- D://
- E://

I guess I'm just wondering if that is possible or if I should just not worry about performance and populate the entirety of the tree from the start.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace CST238___Justin_OBrien___Assign_3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void folderTree_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            populateTree(folderTree, somePath); //help here please =D
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currDirPath.Text = "current directory";
            foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                folderTree.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(drive.Name)); //initialize
            }
        }

        private void populateTree(TreeView tree, string path)
        {
            tree.Nodes.Clear();
            var path1 = new DirectoryInfo( path );
            tree.Nodes.Add(dirNode( path1 ));
        }

        private static TreeNode dirNode(DirectoryInfo di)
        {
            var dNode = new TreeNode(di.Name);
            foreach( var subfolder in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                dNode.Nodes.Add(dirNode( subfolder ));
            }

            foreach( var file in di.GetFiles() )
            {
                dNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            }

            return dNode;
        }
    }
}
```

So this is what I have so far, I decided I would default to just the main drives using the foreach i talked about early and I would handle recursion based on what was clicked by a path from the click action recursively in my function.  I am getting inconsistent results though.  I either have nothing show up at all or the drives are listed but then they dont respond to any click actions, I know im doing something wrong but not sure what.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I strongly recommend adding at least one more tag to the question for the host language you plan to use. Is that C, C++, C#, F#, Java, Ruby, Perl, Python, VB, …? The answer is that you definitely do not want to load everything all at once. It will give you appalling performance if any of the drives is a network drive, and will also chew up a lot of your memory if any of your drives is in the hundred gigabyte or more range (which is usual on desktop or server machines). You should definitely build the list as required, not up front.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I've edited to include C# as the language im using and posted the work ive been doing since I asked the question.

Comment: That should get people who can help you to look at it.  I know C# exists, but that's as far as my knowledge goes.  And posting what you've tried is also usually an important step in improving a question.  The nearer you get to an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), the easier it is for people to help you.

Comment: anyone? /pleadsforhelp